# In DDD, where should validations involving more than one context be done?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

Suppose we have the **Customer** and **Order** contexts in a monolithic application.
When creating the **Order** I need to verify that the **customerId** exists, otherwise the system could remain in an inconsistent state.

Would I have to call the **Customer** application service from the **Order** service? eg. customerAS.exist(customerId)

Could I call the **Customer** repository directly from the **Order** application service ?

Comment: This is not explicit in your question, but the tags suggest you want an answer regarding switching your monolithic application to DDD, is that correct ?

Comment: Also are **Customer** entities handled in the same bounded context than **Order** or not ?

Comment: No @ArwynFr, is DDD in a monolithic application, but from the conceptual point of view it is the same as if it were a microservice or a monolithic. Customer and Orders are in different BC.

Comment: DDD is based on having a domain component where all business code go, and other component(s) where non-business code go. This requires at least a layered-architecture. Unless you want to oppose monolithic to front/api ?

Comment: Also if Customer and Orders are in different BC they cannot be in the same monolith.

Comment: Why not? DDD was born in the era of monoliths

Comment: The concept of a monolith is having a single structure with everything inside. If you make two bounded context, then this is not a monolith anymore, since you have more than one component.

Comment: You can have an application with multiple modules running in the same process.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I call the Customer repository directly from the Order application service ?

The DDD police will not arrest you if you do it 
...but it would be better to don't do it.

The fact is that in that way you are coupling the implementation of the Order domain with the implementation of the Customer domain, and in case later on you want to change the customer domain to don't use repositories, or you want to separate them into two different deployables you will have to refactor this integration point and use something else instead of the repository directly.

Using an interface that explicit the contract and the queries/commands of a domain (the service) helps in decoupling **what** you need to do with **how** you do it, and you will be more free to change the how you do certain stuff reimplementing the same contract the service was already exposing

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose we have the Customer and Order contexts in a monolithic application. When creating the Order I need to verify that the customerId exists, otherwise the system could remain in an inconsistent state.

[What's the business impact](https://web.archive.org/web/20101221183328/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) of being inconsistent in this way:  One dollar? Ten dollars? One hundred billion dollars?

If the business impact of the error is inconsequential, then don't compromise your design and performance to mitigate it.

If the impact would be catastrophic, then you are probably going to need to design your system so that it locks all of the information that must be consistent with making a change.  (You probably don't have this problem, because a [microsecond difference in timing shouldn't make a difference to the business](https://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).)  That will normally mean abandoning the idea that customers and orders are separable systems; perhaps they merge, or parts of the two get moved to a new third system that can manage these information relationships.

In between, we can consider "best effort" mitigations, like consulting an unlocked copy of the information, and hoping the answer found there is fresh.  For instance, we could ask the Customer system for a copy of the answer, but we need to be aware of the fact that *the real answer could change while the answer is in flight*.

In a microservices design, you probably wouldn't want to use a synchronous call to another system that might be down for maintenance or upgrade, but instead to use a *locally cached* copy of the answer, which is intermittently refreshed using some asynchronous mechanism.

Horses for courses.

Comment: I think that the worst case would be to have a public api with many clients that can misuse it, either by mistake or maliciously. I don't think that Facebook or Twitter APIs don't perform that kind of validation.

Comment: It may be less than you think.  Recall that context boundaries are something that you can control with your design.  It might be useful to review Udi Dahan's "Finding Service Boundaries...." talk.

Comment: I disagree, reference ids between contexts are quite common. Let's not talk about whether to validate if a user is suspended or disabled or in any possible state.